# How to give event on force close dialog's ok button

Tags: android

Hi I want to know can I perform my own operations on Force Close Dialog's OK Button ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am afraid you can't do that. But rather you can avoid force close by using uncaught Exception handler.

These links might be helpful.

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/File/android-daisy3-reader/org/geometerplus/zlibrary/ui/android/library/UncaughtExceptionHandler.java.htm

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html

A sample snippet from the above link,

```
public class UncaughtExceptionHandler implements java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
  private final Context myContext;

  public UncaughtExceptionHandler(Context context) {
    myContext = context;
  }

  public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {
    StringWriter stackTrace = new StringWriter();
    exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace));
    System.err.println(stackTrace);

    Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, BugReportActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(BugReportActivity.STACKTRACE, stackTrace.toString());
    myContext.startActivity(intent);

    Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
    System.exit(10);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it is not possible to add functionality to the Android FC dialog. But, what you can do is add your own [uncaughtExceptionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2764394/741249) to handle exceptions. However, when you catch an exception you are a bit limited to what you can do. You cannot show a dialog (see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5519347/741249) why this is).